# Google appending the home page title to every page title in the search results

Tags: google-search, title

I have published my web site a week ago. I have main page with title:

```
drinkIt - Конструктор коктейлей
```

and bunch of child pages (items) with titles like:

```
drinkIt - <item name>
```

It works fine for users, but in google search results (site:drinkit.guru) each item page appears with duplicate title:

```
drinkIt - <item name> - drinkIt - Конструктор коктейлей
```

How can I avoid this?

P.S. Site made like SPA with EmberJS.

Comment: Have you tried putting the brand name (drinkIt) at the end rather than at the beginning of titles?

Comment: Nope. I'm afraid that will change words order. Or no?

Comment: I think Google is seeing "Конструктор коктейлей" (designer cocktails) as your brand because of the positioning of it in your title.   I suspect if you made your titles "Конструктор коктейлей - drinkIt" and "<item name> - drinkIt" then Google would correct itself.

Comment: Interesting... I will try this. Also, I found a notion that google adds brand name (home page title) to all _short_ titles. Maybe it is a reason.

Comment: It adds the brand to short titles, but only if it doesn't think they already have the brand in them.

Comment: If drinkIt is your brand, then your title tag should be *<item name> | drinkIt* or *<item name> : drinkIt*. The | character brands the title on the right while : brands the title on the left. Cheers!!

Comment: I already made <item name> - drinkIt. Or google accepts only ":" as delimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I have changed my titles to: `<item name> - drinkIt` and it's really work. So brand name positioning in the title is really important for google.